# Which low-cost general-purpose camera is better than a cellphone in low-light conditions?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, canon

Currently I am making photos with my Eten M800 cellphone, and they are fine outdoors with good light, but terrible indoors with poor lightning. I would like to buy a camera which can be better at it, and not spend more then about 100 EUR / 150 USD on a used one from eBay.

I've used a Sony Cyber-Shot DSC-W270 a few times, and it makes excellent sharp photos even in poor light, without the need to set anything, and costs about 100$ used on eBay, but it uses Sony MemoryStick cards, and I'd much prefer something using standard SD cards.

As I like hacking things, playing with firmware, I'd prefer something where I can install [CHDK](http://hackaday.com/2008/05/27/how-to-expand-your-camera-with-chdk/) so something from [this list](http://chdk.wikia.com/wiki/FAQ#Q._What_camera_models_are_supported_by_the_CHDK_program.3F).

I've seen good reviews of Canon PowerShot S90, but it costs cheapest 160 EUR / 220 USD, but that's about twice as much as the Sony Cyber-Shot DSC-W270 - is it really that much better to be worth the money?

Because I have the habit of occasionally getting my electronics in wet or dusty conditions, I'm also looking at the Canon PowerShot D10 waterproof camera.

I'd like people not too have red eyes if I shoot with flash indoors, and be able to photograph the underside of my car reasonably sharply without looking into the display.

Is there anything else in that price range that is exceptionally good value for money?

Answer (score 3):

Your list of wants/needs is confusing to me, you have to decide what you must have, and prioritize them. What it sounds like you are looking for is:

- Great low light performance
- Canon CHDK compatible
- Waterproof
- Red eye reduction feature
- Ability to take photos without looking at the display
- $150USD or less used

Canon only has a handful of waterproof cameras, and in your price range even less.

In my opinion, you are not going to find anything that is less expensive then a used Canon S90 that still has good low light performance like it. If anything, you will have to spend even more and get a DSLR to get good performance. The sensors on these pocket cameras just are not capable of getting DSLR like high ISO performance. It all depends on what your requirements are though, and what you think is acceptable.